# Clistview ajax pagination in ajax based page

Tags: php, ajax, yii, pagination, clistview

I have an **ajax web page** which includes **multiple CListView** widgets, the CListView ajax based pagination is working fine but when I reload the whole page with ajax and then I send request of CListView page 2 then it I see 1 request ***Aborted***!!! And on ajax whole page request every time it includes **clistview.js**.

in my contoller

```
$this->renderPartial('_inbox', $data, false, true);
```

in view part

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
 'dataProvider'=> $dataProviderArr_workflow_wise,
 'itemView'=>'_taskRow',
 'id' => 'someid_'.$someid['id'],
));
```

AFter ajax page refresh I have this

Aborted request

GET **http://localhost/app/controller/action/1?Tasks_page=2&ajax=workflows_1** Aborted

GET **http://localhost/app/controller/action/1?Tasks_page=2&ajax=workflows_1** 200 OK